# urxvt triple-click not selecting lines as expected

Tags: linux, command-line, urxvt

Can anyone please explain why left mouse triple-click is not selecting lines for me in `urxvt` ?
To be specfic it sometimes works, but it depends on the nature of the text I'm selecting.

For example, if I triple-click on the output from `ls -l` (example below) it works as I'd expect and extends the selection to the whole line.

```
drwx------  2 john john 4.0K Apr 10 13:52 vFaheu1/
drwx------  2 john john 4.0K Apr  7 22:34 vgtsglC/
drwx------  2 john john 4.0K Apr 10 14:09 vKYxAOy/
drwx------  2 john john 4.0K Apr  9 15:13 vrnQIUR/
```

**BUT** if I triple-click on the output below I get different behaviour depending on where I click:

```
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
```

If I put the mouse locator over the `e` in `Red hat` I have to
click **6 times** (in close succession) to select the whole line. Here's the text I see selected after each click:

1. no text selected
2. `Red`
3. `(Red`
4. `Red Hat 4.8.5-4`
5. `GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)`
6. the whole line

Basically, it seems that `rxvt` is "intelligently" deciding how to extend
the selection depending on the context around the text (e.g. parentheses or brackets).

I'd like to turn this feature off if possible and just have triple-click select the whole line.

I've tried the following, to no avail:

- invoke `urxvt` with `-pe ""` to turn off perl extensions
- `+tcw` & `-tcw` (i.e. without or with `tripleclickwords`)

Environment:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.21 - released: 2014-12-31
rxvt-unicode (urxvt256c) v9.21 - released: 2014-12-31
rxvt-unicode (urxvt256c) v9.21 - released: 2014-12-31
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by disabling the `selection` Perl extension.

I was under the misapprehension that `-pe ""` would disable all extensions (I think I read this somewhere), but it doesn't.

In fact I'm not sure exactly how to disable *all* Perl extensions, but here's how to disable `selection`:

```
urxvt -pe "-selection"
```

And here's how I've done it via X resources:

```
URxvt.perl-ext: default,-selection
```

Now, triple-click always selects lines.